# Demo with jqGrid & AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, jqgrid

i just create a jqGrid within a controller.i want add some buttons in each row with some event within controller.
before in jquery:

```
 option.gridComplete=function () {
        var ids = jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            var cl = ids[i];
            var edit = '<input type="button" onclick="edit()">';
            jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], {
                act: edit
            });
        }
    }
```

someone pelase tell me how to bind ng-click in the edit button
like this
 `var edit = '<input type="button" ng-click="edit()">';`

Comment: This is not right way to make jq grid into controller. you can create directive for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hidden input in html and bind it to it maybe

```
 '<input type="button" onclick="$(hiddenButton).click()">'
```

in your html

```
 <input type="hidden" id="hiddenButton" ng-click="edit()">
```